# Application.run returns nothing, though function is called properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet application where each sheet object has the same methods (`getHeaderRow` and `skipCol`), but are defined slightly differently for each sheet.  Both of these methods are called in the `btnGenerate_DataComments_Click()` method in the DataComments module.  More specifically, as part of the `btnGenerate_DataComments_Click()` method, I want to call the `getHeaderRow` method defined as part of the ActiveSheet's object in the project directory (for example, if I click on the button assigned the `btnGenerate_DataComments_Click()` macro in sheet 5, I want to call `Sheet5.getHeaderRow`).  To accomplish this, I am using `Application.Run`.  Below is my code:

```
Dim str As String: str = "Sheet" & ActiveSheet.Index & ".getHeaderRow"
Dim intHeaderRow As Integer: intHeaderRow = Application.Run(str)
Dim testHeaderRow As Integer: testHeaderRow = Sheet5.getHeaderRow
MsgBox ("Macro: " & str & "; intHeaderRow: " & intHeaderRow & "; testHeaderRow: " & testHeaderRow)
```

and getHeaderRow is defined in all sheets as:

```
Const intHeaderRow = 3
Const intEqpTypeCol = 3

Public Function getHeaderRow() As Integer
    getHeaderRow = intHeaderRow
End Function
```

Though the value of Const intHeaderRow differs from sheet to sheet

However, the msgbox that pops up displays "Macro: Sheet5.getHeaderRow; intHeaderRow: 0; testHeaderRow: 3".  This tells me that the `getHeaderRow` function works, but somehow `Application.Run` is not returning the correct value (3).  In addition, when I step through the debugger, I see that the code does go to the Sheet5.getHeaderRow method when called by `Application.Run` and stores the correct return value in `getHeaderRow`, but when the debugger goes back to the `btnGenerate_DataComments_Click()` method, it doesn't store a value.

I would appreciate any insight into this issue; my project structure is attached below.  Best Regards.

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: A) are you using Option explicit, and B) are these in the same module or are you moving across modules (would assume you only work in module DataComments, but assumptions are bad)?

Comment: Your worksheet indexes mostly do not match the worksheet codenames.  `Sheet5` has Index = 9   You can use `ActiveSheet.CodeName` instead which give you a more direct approach

Comment: Do the sheets have an actual table / `ListObject`? If so, you can discard the two constants and change that to a property e.g. `Public Property Get Table() As ListObject : Set Table = Me.ListObjet(1) : End Property` then work with the actual table, and/or add a `Public Property Get TableHeaderRow() As Long : TableHeaderRow = Table.HeaderRowRange.Row : End Property`, and then `Public Property Get EqpTypeColumn() As Long : EqpTypeColumn = Table.ListColumns("EqpType").Index : End Property` -- then use `CallByName` with `vbGet` against the worksheet object, instead of `Application.Run`.

Comment: Hi Cyril, I am using Option Explicit.  Also, the getHeaderRow method is in the sheet, whereas the btnGenerate_DataComments_Click() module resides in the DataComments module.  Tim, I see your point, and did not know that CodeName existed; I've changed the line to `str = ActiveSheet.CodeName & ".getHeaderRow"`.  However, intHeaderRow still shows as 0.  Mathieu, that is an interesting idea, will check it out -- but still curious why Application.Run would not work.  Thank you all for the responses.

Comment: You don't need to use either `Application.Run` or `CallByName` (assuming the sheets are in the same workbook as the code)  You can just call (eg) `Activesheet.getHeaderRow`

Comment: Tim -- That worked! Simplest solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, this routine has given me a lot of grief over the years! I'd usually avoid using it unless you have to.  Ok, so how have I got this to work.

(Apologies haven't used your code example as I personnally can't work with colons, very hard to read)

```
           'I have found you "must" use an Object variable as follows:
            Dim oExcelApp as Object 'Don't specify Excel.Application
            
            'Don't just use Application.Run as you have, I have found it just won't work as desired, it must be declared in an Object var.
            
            ... your other code here e.g.
            sSub = "Module1.MyRoutine" 'I like to be explicit and include the module
            vArgs() = Array("A","B","C")
            
            set oExcelApp = Excel.Application 'Yes, you can now use Excel.Application, go figure!
            Debug.print "Before: " & vArgs(2)  "C"
            call oExcelApp.run(sSub,vArgs)
            Debug.print "After: " & vArgs(2)   "Holy Cow"

            Private sub MyRoutine(ByRef vArgs as Variant)
                vArgs(2) "Holy Cow!"
            end sub
```

As I said, it works for me, but I'm not inspired with confidence when using the Application.Run routine, e.g. I have noted it does seem to sometimes just end  straight after Application.Run..., you may have more luck than me.